# UITableView not responding anymore after implement UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview, uitapgesturerecognizer

In my view controller, I have a table view and a few custom `UIView`'s. Within the view controller, a `UITapGestureRecognizer` is implemented for some interactive UI work. Now, the `UITableView` is not responding to `UITapGestureRecognizer` anymore. From debugging, it appears that it goes right into the `UITapGestureRecognizer` selector method, and the `didSelectRowAtPath` is never being called.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: I was able to find the problem really quickly. The gestureRecognizer can be added to a specific view. I just added the gestureRecognizer to the view I wanted it to be tracking taps for. Hope this helps for anyone else having the same issue.

Comment: @user1530580 Make an answer and mark it accepted

Comment: please post code that you are written.

Comment: if your issue is solve mark as Acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to Add Tap Gesture on your view.
And Remember `<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>` to Add in .h file.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doubleTap1ImgView:)];
        doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
        doubleTap.delegate = self;


        [self.ImgView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];
        self.ImgView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;




- (void)doubleTap1ImgView:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
            // Do What you want here
}
```